# SQL update many rows using select

Tags: sql

I have a table2 that has the primary key ID of table1. I want you to do an update on table1 depending on the last date of each row compatible with table2. Ex:

```
 tabela 1           tabela2 

 ID DES  CAN ###### ID DATA-
 1  test 0   ###### 1  12/10/2017 
 2  test 0   ###### 1  12/09/2017  
 3  test 0   ###### 2  12/09/2017
 4  test 0   ###### 3  12/10/2017
```

I intend to update only the records of table1 where the IDs in table2 have the current date + 15 days. try this but it does not work.

```
UPDATE table 
SET 
  Col1 = i.Col1, 
  Col2 = i.Col2 
FROM (SELECT ID, Col1, Col2 FROM other_table) i
WHERE i.ID = table.ID
```

Comment: See https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/30/sql-server-update-from-select-statement-using-join-in-update-statement-multiple-tables-in-update-statement/

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And explain how you do the date comparison.  `id`s don't normally store dates.

Answer (score 0):

you can  search update syntax.

update table where column IN ( table join select )

Answer (score 0):

The standard SQL would use two correlated subqueries:

```
UPDATE table
    SET Col1 = (SELECT Col1 FROM other_table i WHERE i.ID = table.ID),
        Col2 = (SELECT Col2 FROM other_table i WHERE i.ID = table.ID) ;
```

You might want a `WHERE` clause to be sure that you have a match.

Some databases allow you to set tuples:

```
UPDATE table
   SET (Col1, Col2) = (SELECT Col1, COl2 FROM other_table i WHERE i.ID = table.ID);
```

Your formulation should work in some databases (notably SQL Server and Postgres).